# Vertially Merged Cells breaking macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found this macro to go through a document and remove decimal points from tables. However, when it comes across a table with vertically merged cells it breaks. Is there a way to get around this without deleting or unmerging the cells?

```
Sub RoundAllNumbersInTables()

    Dim currentTbl As Table
    Dim currentCl As Cell
    Dim currentRow As Row
    Dim currentText As String

    For Each currentTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each currentRow In currentTbl.Rows
            For Each currentCl In currentRow.Cells

                currentText = Trim(Left(currentCl.Range.Text, Len(currentCl.Range.Text) - 2))

                If IsNumeric(currentText) Then
                    currentCl.Range.Text = Format(Round(currentText, 0), "0")
                End If

            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

If I run this now I get `Run time error:5991`

```
Cannot access individual rows in the collection because the table has vertically merged cells.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have vertically merged cells you can switch from parsing the table by row to parsing it by column.

```
  Dim currentCol As Column

  For Each currentTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
      For Each currentCol In currentTbl.Columns
            For Each currentCl In currentCol.Cells
```

But as you won't always know whether a table has merged cells the best option is to iterate through `currentTbl.Range.Cells`

```
  For Each currentTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
      For Each currentCl In currentTbl.Range.Cells
          currentText = Trim(Left(currentCl.Range.Text, Len(currentCl.Range.Text) - 2))

          If IsNumeric(currentText) And Left$(currentText, 1) = "$"  Then
              currentCl.Range.Text = Format(Round(currentText, 0), "$#,###")
          End If

      Next
   Next
```

Comment: This helped a lot thanks. I was using this macro to remove decimal points from tables, however I only wanted it to remove them from text with a $ symbol at the start. Is there any way to incorporate this in? 
currentCl.Range.Text = Format(Round(currentText, 0), "$#,###")
 I changed this line to this. This formats the changed text how I want but it will still select numbers without $ at the start.

Comment: @Jack I have edited the answer to include the test for the $ symbol.